# htaccess rewrite rule for magento index.php single home URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

Magento by default listens to 3 possible url's for reaching the home page:

1. https://www.shop.nl/
2. https://www.shop.nl/index.php
3. https://www.shop.nl/index.php/

Google doesn't like this behaviour, and i'm trying to optimize my shop for search engines. So i went to the .htaccess file of Magento and tried to edit the correct rules. However this does not seem to work.

I tried replacing line 175: `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin($|/)
RewriteRule ^index.php(/(.*))? /$2 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This because it occured to me that magento's back-end doesn't like that i'm removing the index.php from the URL. It works for the root URL. But the problem is i can't view any other pages. All redirect me to the home page.

Does anybody have any suggestions? And i also would like to find out why magento is doing this at all. I can't figure out how this could be usefull.

Notice: I wonderd if it matters that i am running on [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule as **first rule** in your magento .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php/?$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

This will remove `index.php` from original URL (not from the rewritten URI).

Comment: So leave line 175: `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` intact?

Comment: Yes let that be intact. Just make sure above rule is the first rule

Comment: this works for the index.php part but not if i add the last slash so it doesn't change: `https://www.shop.nl/index.php/`

Comment: Nice 301 redirects and the back-end also works just fine, thanks.